# Problem converting class component to functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, react-hooks

I am making a todo app and I continue to improve myself by making the class component a functional component.
I made the most important places (add, delete) of the todo app functional, but I have problems while converting to other components. I would appreciate it if you could check and help.

**Class to functional**:

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
      todos: []
    };

const App = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);
```

**ComponentDidMount to useEffect**

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10")
      .then((res) =>
        this.setState({
          todos: res.data
        })
      )
  }

useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10")
      .then((res) =>
        setTodos({
          todos: res.data // i'm not sure about here.
        })
      )
  }
```

**Class AddTodo to Func AddTodo**

```
  
  Addtodo = (title) => {
    axios
      .post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?", {
        title,
        completed: false
      })
      .then((res) =>
        this.setState({
          todos: [...this.state.todos, res.data]
        })
      )
  }

  const Addtodo = (title) => {
    axios.post("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos", {
      title, 
      completed:false
    }).then((res) => setTodos({
      todos: [...todos, res.data] // I'm not sure about here.
    }))
  }
```

**Class DeleteTodo to Func Deletetodo**

```
deleteTodo = (id) => {
    axios
      .delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
      .then((res) =>
        this.setState({
          todos: [...this.state.todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id)]
        })
      )
  }

  const deleteTodo = (id) => {
    axios.delete(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${id}`)
    .then((res) => setTodos({
      todos:[...todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id)] // not sure
    }))
  }
```

**Class checkmark to func checkmark**

```
  markComplete = (id) => {
    this.setState({
      todos: this.state.todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
        }
        return todo
      })
    })
  }

  const markComplete = (id) => {
    setTodos({
      todos: todos.map((todo) => {
        if (todo.id === id) {
          todo.completed = !todo.completed
        }
        return todo
      })
    })
  }
```

**And last section, I hope I got it right into props.**

```
<Addtodo Addtodo={() => Addtodo()} />

<Todo todos={todos}
    markComplete={() =>markComplete()}
    deleteTodo={() => deleteTodo()}
/>
```

**Todo component: **

```
function Todo({ todos, markComplete, deleteTodo }) {
  return todos.map((todo) => (
    <TodoItem
      key={todo.id}
      markComplete={markComplete}
      deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
      todos={todos}
    />
  ))
}
```

TodoItem component:

```
class TodoItem extends Component {
  render() {
    const { id, title } = this.props.todo // **Can you tell me this part? I did not understand and could not convert.**

    return (
      <div>
        <p>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            onChange={this.props.markComplete.bind(this, id)}
          />
          {""} {title}{" "}
          <button onClick={this.props.deleteTodo.bind(this, id)}>X </button>{" "}
        </p>{" "}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**And last, Addtodo component: (I didn't understand "Addtodo" in onSubmit function. Is this a Props from App.js or classname?**

```
class Addtodo extends Component {
  state = {
    title: ""
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.Addtodo(this.state.title) // // **Can you tell me this part? I did not understand and could not convert.**

    this.setState({
      title: ""
    })
  }

  onChange = (e) =>
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })

  render() {
    return (
      <form
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}

      >
        <input
          type="text"
          name="title"
          onChange={this.onChange}
          value={this.state.title}
          placeholder="Add todo"
         
        />
        <input
          type="Submit"
          name="Submit"
          value="Submit"
          className="btn"
          
        />{" "}
      </form>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `useState` you have each piece of `state` in a var in itself (unless you choose to make it nested), vs. in a class component where the state itself is an object.

So in the setter function you just need to assign the new value and no need to mention the state (`todos`) you want to change.

Change

```
setTodos({
    todos: res.data // i'm not sure about here.
})
```

To

```
setTodos(res.data)
```

And

```
setTodos({
  todos:[...todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id)] // not sure
})
```

To

```
setTodos([...todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id)])
```

Also if you want to pass a function you need to just mention it not call it

```
<Todo todos={todos}
    markComplete={markComplete}
    deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
/>
```

In the `TodoItem component`

```
      // you extract "id" and "title" from "this.props.todo"
const { id, title } = this.props.todo
```

No change is needed as you are still using a class component for this.

In `Addtodo component` you call the function passed along to it and pass the title to the function.

```
this.props.Addtodo(this.state.title)
```

And since you are still using a class component for this you don't need any changes.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. Your explanation helped me a lot. I made the corrections you made in the AddTodo part. Can you check last section. Did i get it right?

Comment: @navarrro ninca Are all sections in one component?

Comment: @navarrro ninca See my update to the answer, (it is a little hard for me to see your structure but this is what it looks to me)

Comment: I follow your updates. I added other components to the bottom of the question.

Comment: @navarrro ninca I added some more updates, let me know if you still have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

**For componentDidMount to useEffect**
You have add empty array [] as the second parameter to useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=10")
      .then((res) =>
        setTodos({
          todos: res.data // i'm not sure about here.
        })
      )
  }, []);
```